# What fields should be serialized for Symfony´s User and its related entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have my `User` Entity and it is related to another Entity named `Business`

```
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var Business
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Business")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="business_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $business;

    // ...
```

Now I noticed that on every change `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken` by default is serializing entire User Entity including related Business.

Now the first problem I faced was introducing $file field for Business entity where one field is not mapped and stores `UploadedFile` which cannot be serialized.

```
/**
 * @var UploadedFile
 */
private $file;
```

Now whenever I try to upload a file I would get an error

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed

Thrown by `Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php`

Ofcourse I don´t need that field to be serialized, but I also have no idea which fields MUST be serialized not to lose proper Symfony logic.

So far I just implemented `\Serializable` and serialized just `id` of Business entity

```
class Business implements \Serializable
{
    // ...

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id
        ]);
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
```

Now I dont get an error, BUT I have no idea if I should be serializing all fields excluding $file or leaving $id is just fine. Also why it is and why do we need to serialize User relations?

Comment: The serialized info is used at the beginning of a request to load a current copy of the user.  Out of the box, the Doctrine UserProvider just uses the id so that it why it works.  However, the serialized info can optionally be used to determine if any user related database information has been changed since the last request.  In particular you might want to check if the password has changed.  That is where the EquatableInterface comes in.  Take a look at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User::isEqualTo to see what is normally checked.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing by the same problem here.

And I lost spend much time tripping to find the problem, the solution is transform your entity on Serializable and create the methods. **But before this you need to destroy/logout of your session that you was logged.**

On my case I was implementing the Serializable but the problem persisted, because I wasn't logout of my old session which doesn't exists the informations related a Business Serialized on this case.

So the steps is:

1. Logout (if the form that you are using of entity cited, just works if the user is logged)
2. Turn the entity to Serializable

```php
use Serializable;

class Business implements Serializable
{
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

It works for me!

If persist I found some another solutions using the ignore annotation on the field that throw the error, it's possible to works too.

```php
class Business implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="images", fileNameProperty="image")
     *
     * @Ignore()
     */
    private $imageFile;
}
```